# Subscribing on Observable<number | string> (union type) is giving NaN for string values

Tags: angular, typescript, union-types

In a component I have a public member defined like so:

```
public documentId$: Observable<number | string>;
```

Basically the document ID can be an integer or a string. In `ngOnInit` I have:

```
this.documentId$.subscribe(value => {
    // do some stuff with value
    // when value is a string, it is NaN
});
```

However, this does not work when the document ID is a string. It just comes in as `NaN`. Do observables of union types not work? Is there a way around this?

Comment: How is documentId$ assigned? The types should not actually modify that value, they are simply telling your IDE what types it can expect to be returned.

Comment: It's likely that there's an issue with the data. The union type doesn't actually have any impact on the value you receive in the subscribe

Comment: The type has no influence on the value. You can declare Observable<boolean> or whatever you will still have `NaN`.

Comment: You guys are right. The value was converted to `NaN` beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a problem using the union type. Inspect the data you are getting. This one works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rur73e

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  private subject = new Subject<number | string>();
  public documentId$: Observable<number | string> = this.subject.asObservable();

  ngOnInit() {
  this.documentId$.subscribe(value => {
    // do some stuff with value
    // when value is a string, it is NaN
    console.log(value);
  });
  this.subject.next("abc");
  this.subject.next(3);
  this.subject.next(Date.now());
  }
}
```

The produced output in the console is:

```
abc
3
1571682486949
```

Comment: You are right. The value was converted to `NaN` beforehand. I was trying to update `Observable<number>` to `Observable<number | string>` everywhere it's used, but missed a couple things. First, a child component with an input `Input() public documentId$: Observable<number>` was not causing IDE errors since it's passed in through HTML. Second, the subscriber is getting the value from a URL query parameter, and I was unaware that there is a resolver that calls `parseInt` on this value. Apologies for the question and thanks for the help.